# Automated Test Results - JUnit -> How to do ordinary grouping/formatting?

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, tfsbuild

I am new around here, I have done a lot of googling, searching on this site and asking around and have not found a satisfactory answer.

I develop automated tests, UI as well as API. These are then run by TFS and the results are put into a JUnit xml document, which is then read by TFS. But alas the formatting is atrocious and leaves one unable to use the output for anything.

Vis:

[image: Grain Api tests]

There is no information about the Test Suite (which is there in the XML), the actual request sent (which is in the log) or response received and so one is left with absolutely no context to understand what has actually taken place (which request was sent, what test group/suite it belongs to and what any potential error was).

As far as I have been able to uncover, TFS simply has little to no support of proper test result formatting when it comes to automated testing. I am very surprised by this in 2018. Not even any documentation that allows me to develop my report structure/format in some kind of script.

What alternatives do I have? Can I automatically attach a generated HTML report somehow in TFS? Can I output more info anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Test Suite`, `Owner`, `Priority` etc...

And you can double click the specific test result and navigate to the test run Summary to see more information there, also you can attach files there.

More information please see [Review continuous test results after a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=vsts)

[image]

Comment: @Jacob Damkjær Have you resolved the issue? any update?